# In Mysql, can we return an array from a subquery

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In postgres, if we want to retrieve any array of data from a subquery we just use array constructor. Similarly to that in Mysql, is there any way to retrieve an array of data from a subquery?

Example:

- In role we have schema like id, name, description
- In user table we have like id, email
- In user_role table we have schema like id, role_id,user_id

user_role hasMany roles.

I need a result like  user_role.id,role.name
and role.name should have an array of values.

Please check below example
https://mkyong.com/database/convert-subquery-result-to-array/

Comment: don't know what you mean by "an array".  please show schema, sample data, and desired results for your sample data and maybe someone will be able to determine what you mean

Comment: I'm guessing you meant "result like user.id,..." not "result like user_role.id,..."?

Comment: I wasn't able to imagine how or why you would use a subquery for this; if you really need to, please do show sample data and desired results and an attempt at a query to help me understand

Answer (score 1):

mysql doesn't have an array type.  You can return a comma separated list of role names:

```
select user.id, group_concat(role.name order by role.name)
from user
join user_role on user_role.user_id=user.id
join role on role.id=user_role.role_id
group by user.id
```

or a string containing a json array, e.g. `["role a name","role b name"]`:

```
select user.id, json_arrayagg(role.name order by role.name)
from user ...
```

Note that group_concat returns a string that will be truncated at @@group_concat_max_len characters, a system variable that defaults to 1024 in mysql.

Comment: Nice idea with the JSON, less clunky and error prone than `group_concat`.